# Dependency libmpc2 Debian 8.3

Tags: debian

I'm trying to install some development tools in Debian 8.3 Jessie with apt-get, `cpp-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf` and `gcc-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf` but I'm getting a dependency problem with `libmpc2`.

```
root@debian-host:~# apt-get install cpp-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf gcc-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'cpp-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'cpp-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf' for regex 'gcc-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf'
Note, selecting 'gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf-base' for regex 'gcc-4.7.arm-linux-gnueabihf'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or
been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
cpp-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Depends: libmpc2 but it is not installable
gcc-4.7-arm-linux-gnueabihf : Depends: libmpc2 but it is not installable
                           Recommends: libc6-dev-armhf-cross (>= 2.13-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Now seems that only `libmpc3` is available to this Debian version, how can I point to the new version and solve these dependencies problem?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [debian-wiki-CrossToolchains](https://wiki.debian.org/CrossToolchains), you need to add the the `Debian Cross-toolchains` repository:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/crosstools.list
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/ jessie main
```

Import the key:

```
curl http://emdebian.org/tools/debian/emdebian-toolchain-archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install crossbuild-essential-armhf
```

> This will pull in the required packages to cross-build for the target architecture, namely `libc6-dev`:, `gcc`-, `g++`- and `dpkg-cross`. (**Note that dpkg-cross was removed from jessie, but remains in the Debian Cross-toolchains repository**).